# how to solve this type of page to set IN magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I have created theme and refresh homepage then this type of page is coming how to get complete homepage ? I did deploy and clean cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running followings in given order.

```
rm -rf var/{cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed}
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Go the magento root folder and run this command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

Go the magento root folder check this file **.htaccess**

Comment: No any change how to go .htaccess folder ?

Comment: magento root folder .htaccess file is available or not its hidden file so cntrl+H and then showing

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I also apply all command but no change

Comment: @sannikalariya have you checked in pub/static folder. Is there .htaccess  file exist ?

Comment: yes I also check no any commands working now

Comment: help me solve this error?

Comment: @sannikalariya Have you enable rewrite module ? Are you using windows or linux ?

Comment: I am using linux @Mukeshbhai

Comment: @sannikalariya run this command "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and "sudo systemctl restart apache2"